# Is inflow's fluid subject to gravity?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I just want to know if the fluid emitted from an inflow object, is subjected to scene's gravity... So let's say I have an inflow object which emit fluid, and it's at 10 of height: does the fluid fall to the ground?
(Excuse me if my English is not perfect but I'm not English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer: Yes it does.**

I set up a simple scene to test this.  Cube scaled up be 10, set as the Fluid Domain.  Added cylinder set as Fluid Inflow.  I then baked, and it dripped out of the cylinder, landing on the bottom of the domain.

If you would like, here is a .blend file with my test scene, however you may need to bake the fluid sim again (should take about a minute):

[image]